# Microsoft Ad SDK for UWP Crashes a lot (out_of_memory, fireevent)

Tags: out-of-memory

Since the creators update for Windows we have started getting an insane number of crashes, all coming deep from withing the Ad SDK and some from edgehtml.dll.

We are using C# (UWP platform) + Monogame.

We plugged in handlers for unhandled exceptions and for dispatcher but we didn't have much luck cathing them.

Below I have pasted 2 stack traces from the 2 most common errors:

```
0   XXXXXXOurGameApp    out_of_memory   0x0000000000000000
1   unknown.dll [.ecxr] 0x0000000000000000
2   KERNELBASE.dll  RaiseFailFastException  0x0000000000000000
3   edgehtml.dll    Abandonment::InduceAbandonment  0x0000000000000000
4   edgehtml.dll    Abandonment::OutOfMemory    0x0000000000000000
5   edgehtml.dll    Abandonment::InduceHRESULTAbandonment   0x0000000000000000
6   edgehtml.dll    CWebPlatformTridentHost::EnsureWebPlatformProxyRoot 0x0000000000000000
7   edgehtml.dll    CWUCLayerManager::GetWebPlatformProxyRoot   0x0000000000000000
8   edgehtml.dll    CWUCLayerManager::Initialize    0x0000000000000000
9   edgehtml.dll    RefCounted_CWUCLayerManager,MultiThreadedRefCount_::Create_CWUCLayerManager,CDXSystem * __ptr64,LayerManagerTarget * __ptr64 & __ptr64,bool & __ptr64,bool & __ptr64,bool & __ptr64,unsigned long & __ptr64_    0x0000000000000000
10  edgehtml.dll    CDXSystem::CreateLayerManager   0x0000000000000000
11  edgehtml.dll    CDoc::EnsureLayerManager    0x0000000000000000
12  edgehtml.dll    CView::Activate 0x0000000000000000
13  edgehtml.dll    CDoc::RunningToInPlace  0x0000000000000000
14  edgehtml.dll    CServer::TransitionTo   0x0000000000000000
15  edgehtml.dll    CServer::UIActivate 0x0000000000000000
16  edgehtml.dll    CWebPlatformTridentHost::ActivateMe 0x0000000000000000
17  edgehtml.dll    CServer::ActivateView   0x0000000000000000
18  edgehtml.dll    CServer::DoUIActivate   0x0000000000000000
19  edgehtml.dll    CServer::DoVerb 0x0000000000000000
20  edgehtml.dll    CWebPlatformTridentHost::_Activate  0x0000000000000000
21  edgehtml.dll    CWebPlatformTridentHost::_OnSetClientSite   0x0000000000000000
22  edgehtml.dll    CWebPlatformTridentHost::SetClientSite  0x0000000000000000
23  edgehtml.dll    CWebPlatform::_OnInPlaceActivate    0x0000000000000000
24  edgehtml.dll    CWebPlatform::_OnActivateChange 0x0000000000000000
25  edgehtml.dll    CCoreWebViewTaskHandler::_OleActivateWebPlatform    0x0000000000000000
26  edgehtml.dll    CCoreWebViewTaskHandler::Initialize 0x0000000000000000
27  edgehtml.dll    CCoreWebView::Initialize    0x0000000000000000
28  EdgeManager.dll WebViewManager::CreateCoreWebViewPrivate    0x0000000000000000
29  EdgeManager.dll CCoreWebViewControl::Initialize 0x0000000000000000
30  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::CoreWebViewHost::CreateComponent  0x0000000000000000
31  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::WebView::CreateComponent  0x0000000000000000
32  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CWebView::CreateComponent   0x0000000000000000
33  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CComponentHost::EnsureComponentCreated  0x0000000000000000
34  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::WebView::OnPropertyChanged2   0x0000000000000000
35  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::DependencyObject::NotifyPropertyChanged   0x0000000000000000
36  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CDependencyObject::SetEffectiveValue    0x0000000000000000
37  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CDependencyObject::UpdateEffectiveValue 0x0000000000000000
38  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CDependencyObject::SetValue 0x0000000000000000
39  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement::SetValue    0x0000000000000000
40  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement::SetValue 0x0000000000000000
41  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CWebView::SetValue  0x0000000000000000
42  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DependencyObject_SetValue   0x0000000000000000
43  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetValueCore    0x0000000000000000
44  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetValueByKnownIndex_double_    0x0000000000000000
45  Microsoft.Advertising.dll   Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement::Width::[Windows::UI::Xaml::IFrameworkElement]::set 0x0000000000000000
46  Microsoft.Advertising.dll   Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::AdvertisingWebBrowser::OnSizeChanged 0x0000000000000000
47  Microsoft.Advertising.dll   `Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventHandler::RoutedEventHandler_Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::AdvertisingWebBrowser,void (__cdecl Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::AdvertisingWebBrowser::*)  0x0000000000000000
48  Microsoft.Advertising.dll   Windows::UI::Xaml::SizeChangedEventHandler::[Windows::UI::Xaml::SizeChangedEventHandler::__abi_IDelegate]::__abi_Windows_UI_Xaml_SizeChangedEventHandler___abi_IDelegate____abi_Invoke  0x0000000000000000
49  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase_DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::ISizeChangedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::ISizeChangedEventArgs_::Raise    0x0000000000000000
50  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkElement::OnSizeChanged   0x0000000000000000
51  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::DXamlCore::RaiseEvent 0x0000000000000000
52  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CLayoutManager::RaiseSizeChangedEvents  0x0000000000000000
53  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CLayoutManager::UpdateLayout    0x0000000000000000
54  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CCoreServices::NWDrawTree   0x0000000000000000
55  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpBrowserHost::OnTick 0x0000000000000000
56  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpDispatcher::Tick    0x0000000000000000
57  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage  0x0000000000000000
58  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CDeferredInvoke::DispatchQueuedMessage  0x0000000000000000
59  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpDispatcher::MessageTimerCallbackStatic  0x0000000000000000
60  CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft__CoreUI__Dispatch__TimeoutHandler$CallbackThunk   0x0000000000000000
61  CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::TimeoutManager::Callback_OnDispatch    0x0000000000000000
62  CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::EventLoop::Callback_RunCoreLoop    0x0000000000000000
63  CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter::OnUserDispatch    0x0000000000000000
64  CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter_DoWork 0x0000000000000000
65  CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter_WindowProc 0x0000000000000000
66  user32.dll  UserCallWinProcCheckWow 0x0000000000000000
67  user32.dll  DispatchMessageWorker   0x0000000000000000
68  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage  0x0000000000000000
69  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessagesInternal  0x0000000000000000
70  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents   0x0000000000000000
71  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop    0x0000000000000000
72  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop 0x0000000000000000
73  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run   0x0000000000000000
74  twinapi.appcore.dll _lambda_3c558768873f4b5b0b4a338b4722411c_::operator 0x0000000000000000
75  SHCore.dll  _WrapperThreadProc  0x0000000000000000
76  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk 0x0000000000000000
77  ntdll.dll   RtlUserThreadStart
```

Stack trace 2:

```
0   edgehtml.dll    Tree::SHoldForceScriptingModeToken::SHoldForceScriptingModeToken    0x000000000000002C
1   edgehtml.dll    CBase::FireEvent    0x000000000000008C
2   edgehtml.dll    CWindow::Fire_onbeforeunload    0x000000000000004E
3   edgehtml.dll    COmWindowProxy::Fire_onbeforeunload 0x000000000000016B
4   edgehtml.dll    COmWindowProxy::ExecRefresh 0x00000000000002D4
5   edgehtml.dll    GWndAsyncTask::Run  0x000000000000001B
6   edgehtml.dll    HTML5TaskScheduler::RunReadiedTask  0x0000000000000208
7   edgehtml.dll    HTML5TaskScheduler::RunReadiedTasks 0x00000000000000E3
8   edgehtml.dll    NormalPriorityAtInputEventLoopDriver::DriveRegularPriorityTaskExecution 0x00000000000000A9
9   edgehtml.dll    GlobalWndProc   0x0000000000000162
10  user32.dll  UserCallWinProcCheckWow 0x00000000000002AD
11  user32.dll  DispatchMessageWorker   0x000000000000019F
12  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage  0x00000000000000FE
13  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessagesInternal  0x00000000000000AE
14  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents   0x000000000000007B
15  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop    0x000000000000004C
16  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop 0x000000000000004C
17  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run   0x000000000000003A
18  twinapi.appcore.dll _lambda_3c558768873f4b5b0b4a338b4722411c_::operator 0x00000000000000C4
19  SHCore.dll  _WrapperThreadProc  0x00000000000000F5
20  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk 0x0000000000000014
21  ntdll.dll   RtlUserThreadStart  0x0000000000000021
```

Has anyone experience anything like this?